# How can we share a variable from state in a different scope in a custom hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, redux-toolkit

I am trying to understand why the console.log(batches) is always empty even after I dispatch the new array

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useCallback} from "react";

const useAlterBatches = () => {

const batches = useSelector((state)=> state.batches.batches) || [];

const onQuantityChange = useCallback(( quantity, item, value) => {
  
  let newArr = [];
  let newItem = {...item} //item is an object

  console.log(batches)

   newArr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(batches)); //deep copy of array of objects
      const index = newArr.findIndex(
        (item) => item.batchId=== newRecord.batchId
      );
      if (index > -1 && value > 0) {
        newArr[index].selectedQuantity = value > quantity ? quantity : value;
      } else if (index > -1 && value <= 0) {
        newArr.splice(index, 1);
      } else {
        newRecord.selectedQuantity = value;
        newArr.push(newRecord);
      }
      return dispatch(setBatches(newArr));
    },
    [batches]
  );

}

export default useAlterBatches;


... 
// This is the component I am using. The values are parameters are correct always.
       <NumberInput
          onChange={(value) => onQuantityChange(text, record, value)}
        />
...
```

I try to get the variable batches from selector inside my function but its not updating.
I want to check if the item is already in the batches with the correct value but its always empty even though I dispatch the newArr with an element inside.
What I am expecting is for the batches variable to be updated in the callback function.